# Open dialog ( window) form file PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, windows

( How can i link two file ( two dialog) )
when i click on Open Second i want to go to another page ( window)

Here is the code for two file

Home.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QPushButton, QApplication, QLabel

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
   def __init__(self):
     super(MainWindow, self).__init__()


    btn = QPushButton('Open Second', self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   MW = MainWindow()
   MW.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

SecondWindow.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QPushButton, QApplication, QLabel

class SecondWindow(QMainWindow):
   def __init__(self):
     super(SecondWindow, self).__init__()



if __name__ == '__main__':
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   MW = SecondWindow()
   MW.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: [Here is a an answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49069756/6594646).  I think this may work for you.

Comment: also have a look here: [Switching between frames](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48724047/4464653)